# Filter array by comparing property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Ok i have an array as following

```
const services = [
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "duration":{
               "start":"10",
               "end":"11"
            },
            "serviceId":215
         },
         {
            "duration":{
               "start":"4",
               "end":"5"
            },
            "serviceId":37
         },
         
      ],
      "title":"1632767400000"
   },
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "duration":{
               "start":"9",
               "end":"11"
            },
            "serviceId":215
         },
         {
            "duration":{
               "start":"2",
               "end":"3"
            },
            "serviceId":37
         },
         
      ],
      "title":"1632767400000"
   },
]
```

As you can see i have anoth array (`data`) inside my main array which has multiple objects.

i want to filter these data, for example i want to get data which has start and end duration inbetween 9 and 11.

So my final output of the filtered data must be as follows

```
  const services = [
       {
          "data":[
             {
                "duration":{
                   "start":"10",
                   "end":"11"
                },
                "serviceId":215
             },
           
          ],
          "title":"1632767400000"
       },
       {
          "data":[
             {
                "duration":{
                   "start":"9",
                   "end":"11"
                },
                "serviceId":215
             },
            
             
          ],
          "title":"1632767400000"
       },
    ]
```

I have tried something like the following

```
 const test = services.map((item) => {
      return item.data.filter((service) => {
        return (
          parseInt(service.duration.start) >=
            9 &&
          parseInt(service.duration.end) <=
            11
        );
      });
    });
```

But it only returns the `data` elements array and not the full array like i need. How do i filter `data` arrays in my main array and keep the original structure of the main array.

FYI: any lodash solutions are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

`services` is an array of objects, so first you have to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and return an object will all properties as `...o` and `data` with filtered objects whose `duration.start <= 11`

```
services.map((o) => ({
  ...o,
  data: o.data.filter(
    (obj) => +obj.duration.start >= 9 && +obj.duration.end <= 11
  ),
}));
```

```js
const services = [
  {
    data: [
      {
        duration: {
          start: "10",
          end: "11",
        },
        serviceId: 215,
      },
      {
        duration: {
          start: "4",
          end: "5",
        },
        serviceId: 37,
      },
    ],
    title: "1632767400000",
  },
  {
    data: [
      {
        duration: {
          start: "9",
          end: "11",
        },
        serviceId: 215,
      },
      {
        duration: {
          start: "2",
          end: "3",
        },
        serviceId: 37,
      },
    ],
    title: "1632767400000",
  },
];

const result = services.map((o) => {
  return {
    ...o,
    data: o.data.filter((obj) => +obj.duration.start >= 9 && +obj.duration.end <= 11),
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response data is dealing only with the `data` node in the services array.

**Debugging your map function**

```
services.map((item) => {
  return item.data.filter((service) => {
    return (
      parseInt(service.duration.start) >=
        9 &&
      parseInt(service.duration.end) <=
        11
    );
  });
});
```

Your map function loops through `services` array. On looping the array it filters the data node and check the condition and returns the data nodes which satisfies that condition. **Please Note** it reurns only the data nodes

You have to send not just the data nodes, it should use the all the nodes in each objects of `services` array. This can be done using spread operator like `{data, ...restNodes}`. Here the each object from `services` array will be splitted into two set. The `data` node from each object of will be available in the variable called `data` and rest all variables will be available in `restNodes` variable.

So in map, return the filter action on the `data` node aswell as the `restNodes` variable. So this will give all the data in each nodes from `services` array and filtered data from `data` node.

```js
const services = [
    {
        "data": [
            { "duration": { "start": "10", "end": "11" }, "serviceId": 215 },
            { "duration": { "start": "4", "end": "5" }, "serviceId": 37 },

        ],
        "title": "1632767400000"
    },
    {
        "data": [
            { "duration": { "start": "9", "end": "11" }, "serviceId": 215 },
            { "duration": { "start": "2", "end": "3" }, "serviceId": 37 },

        ],
        "title": "1632767400000"
    },
];
const output = services.map(({data, ...restNodes}) => {
    return {
        data: data.filter((service) => {
            return (
                parseInt(service.duration.start) >=
                9 &&
                parseInt(service.duration.end) <=
                11
            );
        }),
        ...restNodes,
    };
});
console.log(output);
```